# Put buttons at bottom of screen with LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, android-linearlayout

I have the following code, how do I make it so that the 3 buttons are at the bottom?

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/observer"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        tools:context=".asdf"
        android:weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what's this view wrapped in? a frame layout? relative layout?

Comment: Your code contains a typo. By `android:weight="1"` you probably meant `android:layout_weight="1"`. This isn't your problem though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to align views at the bottom of the screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386866/how-to-align-views-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen)

Comment: It might be easier to use the space layout found in the toolbox. You can place it on top of the existing layout above the buttons and size it and it will push them to the bottom.

Comment: You can find a lot of different solutions in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989883/android-layout-with-listview-between-a-top-bar-and-bottom-bar

Answer (score 309, accepted):

You need to ensure four things:

- Your outside `LinearLayout` has `layout_height="match_parent"`
- Your inside `LinearLayout` has `layout_weight="1"` and `layout_height="0dp"`
- Your `TextView` has `layout_weight="0"`
- You've set the gravity properly on your inner `LinearLayout: android:gravity="center|bottom"`

Notice that `fill_parent` does not mean "take up all available space". However, if you use `layout_height="0dp"` with `layout_weight="1"`, then a view will take up all available space ([Can't get proper layout with "fill_parent"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254018/cant-get-proper-layout-with-fill-parent)).

Here is some code I quickly wrote up that uses two LinearLayouts in a similar fashion to your code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/db1_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/cow"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="145dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks like similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Voted up just for the note on how to get a view to fill up all available space! Thank you, great answer!

Comment: Those Lint warnings...!

Comment: This is not best solution becoz after that you cant set view at the center of remaining screen .........................so best solution award goes to  this answer -http://stackoverflow.com/a/26140793/4741746

Comment: Can you please describe the significance of `layout_weight="0"` or what it actually does?

Answer (score 35):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` and align it to the bottom with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: is it not possible using linear layout?

Comment: It is. Like @AND_DEV already said: Use `layout_weight="1"`. With this your LinearLayout will occupy the height left on the screen; now you can set the gravity of your Buttons to bottom.

Comment: Relativelayouts are hard to read, almost never do what you want and are generally awful to maintain. I'd take the performance hit of 30 linearlayouts over 1 relativelayout any day of the week, simply because it saves hours of frustrating fiddling.

Comment: @Ahmed i think the question asked is very clear as it is for LinearLayout, But answered for RelativityLayout and Brian Attwell answered clearly with android:gravity="center|bottom" !

Comment: @Gopi.cs I'm really not sure why you're commenting on an answer that I gave more than 6(!) years ago. It's 2019, just use a ConstraintLayout.

Comment: android:layout_alignParentBottom is not available as propertie, is it deprecated?

Comment: @Windgate make sure that your parent layout is also a `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 14):

Create Relative layout and inside that layout create your button with this line

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Comment: additionally adding `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` to also center it horizontally makes this a great solution.

Comment: Great Trick. Thanks

Comment: but why I don't have that property available in most of my elements and layouts?

Comment: Such a simple solution, this solved so many issues. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by taking a Frame layout as parent Layout and then put linear layout inside it. Here is a example:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"      
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
     android:textSize="16sp"/>




</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    />
 </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

first create file name it as `footer.xml`
put this code inside it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="78dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
 android:layout_weight=".15"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_dark_background_tile" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lborder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/overlay" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/unknown"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/notcolor" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/open"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/openit"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/color"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/colored" />
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rborder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/frames"
        android:layout_weight=".14" />


</LinearLayout>
```

then create **header.xml** and put this code inside it.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_dark_background_tile" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight=".18"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/share" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/save" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/set"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/set" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fix"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rotate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_rotate" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/stock"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".14"
        android:background="@drawable/action_bar_left_button"
        android:src="@drawable/stock" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then in your `main_activity.xml` and put this code inside it :-

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/relt"
android:background="@drawable/background" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="78dp"
    android:id="@+id/down"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        layout="@layout/footer" >
    </include>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/down"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inc"
   >  
    </ImageView> 
    <include layout="@layout/header"
        android:id="@+id/inc"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"></include>
```

happy coding :)

Comment: Does the order matter? I noticed you put the footer as the first element, and the header as the last.

Comment: @MartinKonecny no it does't matter because RelativeLayout has its own attributes so you can control where to other layouts fit inside of it. like : layout_below , etc.

Answer (score 3):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:id="@+id/LinearLayouts02"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:gravity="bottom|end">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/texts1"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="2"
android:text="@string/forgotpass"
android:padding="7dp"
android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="50dp"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
android:topRightRadius="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add layout_weight="1" to in your linearLayout which having Buttons.

**Edit :-** let me make it simple

follow something like below, tags name may not be correct, it is just an Idea

```
<LL>// Top Parrent LinearLayout
   <LL1 height="fill_parent" weight="1" "other tags as requirement"> <TV /><Butons /></LL1> // this layout will fill your screen.
   <LL2 height="wrap_content" weight="1"  orientation="Horizontal" "other tags as requirement"> <BT1 /><BT2/ ></LL2> // this layout gonna take lower part of button height of your screen

<LL/> TOP PARENT CLOSED
```

Comment: adding anroid:layout_weight="1" does not move the linear layout (and buttons) down to the bottom...

Comment: @AND_DEV, you forgot to set android:gravity. Right now, the buttons will still be at the top, even though the LinearLayout that contains them fills the entire bottom area.

Comment: No , Buttons will be in LL2 and that will be in bottom area. Can set Gravity if OP wants Button in exact bottom line. I was just giving a rough Idea, so he can do it according to his requirement.

Comment: Do I read you correctly, that you are using `LL1` element as spacer, so everything next will be at the bottom? Pretty neat trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can bundle your **Button(s)** within a  **RelativeLayout** even if your Parent Layout is Linear. Make Sure the outer most parent has **android:layout_height** attribute set to **match_parent**.
And in that Button tag add
 **'android:alignParentBottom="True" '**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Space` widget with `layout_weight=1` to fill up the space between your widgets and the bottom buttons. See example:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/date_hint">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/date_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/time_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/time_hint">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/time_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:inputType="datetime" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/food_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/food_hint">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/food_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/calories_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="@string/calories_hint">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/calories_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to manifest - to the corresponding activity:

```
  <activity android:name="MyActivity"
    ...
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    ...
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to put a complete Linear Layout at the bottom in Linear Layout. When I tried using the "layout_gravity" to bottom it was not working. So I changed the root layout to the Frame Layout and it worked perfectly.

So If you want to put a layout at bottom try using Frame Layout and put everything else inside a nested Linear or Relative Layout.